# How to find root

Tags: real-analysis, roots

Let $ f(x) =a_1+a_2cosx +a_3 cos2x$. If $|a_1|+|a_2|<|a_3|$ , show that $f $ has at  least two  real roots in $[0,\pi] $

Soultion

$$f (0) = a_1+a_2 +a_3$$
$$f (\frac{\pi}{2})=a_1-a_3 $$
$$f (\pi)=a_1- a_2 +a_3$$

I do not know how to use the formula of the question to prove $f(0), f(\pi)$ Less or greater  $0$  to prove that there is  root ?

Thanks

Comment: You have already done. All the three values are decided by a3.

Answer (score 0):

Try $cos(2x)=2cos^2(x) -1$ which is a quadratic in y= cos(x) (which varies between -1 and +1 as x varies in [0,pi]

Answer (score 0):

Obviously $a_{3}$ can't be zero. Assume $a_{3}\gt0$ then $a_{3}=|a_{3}|\gt|a_{2}|+|a_{1}|$ and we get $a_{3}\gt|a_{2}|+|a_{1}|\ge-a_{1}-a_{2}$ and $a_{3}\gt|a_{2}|+|a_{1}|\ge-a_{1}+a_{2}$. Then we conclude $a_{3}+a_{2}+a_{1}\gt0$ and $a_{3}-a_{2}+a_{1}\gt0$ therefore $f(\pi)\gt0$ and $f(0)\gt0$. It remains to show that $f({\pi\over2})<0.$ However this is also obvious since $a_{3}>a_{1}+|a_{2}|$ and we get $a_{1}-a_{3}<-|a_{2}|$ and $a_{1}$ can't be equal to $a_{3}$ (proof by contradiction) so $f({\pi\over2})<0$ and we conclude using Intermediate Value Theorem that the function stated above has at least one root in [0,$\pi\over2$] and in [$\pi\over2$,$\pi$]. Setting $a_{3}\lt0$ is similar.